# Unable to get Tumblr API OAuth Request token in Nodejs

Tags: node.js, oauth, tumblr

I am having a hard time trying to connect to the Tumblr API via Node. 
It is not even showing me the request_tokens for me to proceed

```
var OAuth = require('oauth').OAuth
var oa = new OAuth(
  "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/request_token",
  "http://www.tumblr.com/oauth/access_token",
  tumblrClientId,
  tumblrClientSecret,
  "1.0A",
  tumblrCallback,
  "HMAC-SHA1"
);

 oa.getOAuthRequestToken(
      function(error, oauth_token, oauth_token_secret, results) {
        if (error) {
          console.log(error);
          res.send("Authentication Failed!");

        }
        else {

          data = {
            token: oauth_token,
            token_secret: oauth_token_secret
          };
          console.log("OAuthToken"+data.oauth_token);
          console.log("OAuthTokenSecret"+data.oauth_token_secret);


        }
      }
    );
```

The output of my console.log statements is :
   {}

Answer (score 0):

For the so called `authorization_code` grant type (web app OAuth flow), it's better to use something more sophisticated that just the bare `oauth` module.

You can use [**Grant**](https://github.com/simov/grant) which is OAuth middleware for Express, Koa and Hapi, and it supports Tumblr as well.

So basically your code might look like this (in case you are using Express):

```
var express = require('express')
  , session = require('express-session')
var Grant = require('grant-express')
  , grant = new Grant({
  server:{host:'localhost:3000', protocol:'http'}
  tumblr:{
    key:'[CONSUMER_KEY]',
    secret:'[CONSUMER_SECRET]',
    callback:'/handle_tumblr_callback'
  }
})

var app = express()
app.use(session({secret:'keyboard cat'}))
// mount grant
app.use(grant)
// other middlewares ...
```

For `redirect_uri` in your OAuth app you should set `http://localhost:3000/connect/tumblr/callback`

There is a [lengthy article](https://scotch.io/tutorials/implement-oauth-into-your-express-koa-or-hapi-applications-using-grant) about OAuth in general and how to use Grant as well. More examples can be found [here](https://github.com/simov/grant/tree/master/example).